# Get value from one component and use it in another.

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have two component files in my Angular 2 app - `home.ts` and `folder-selector.ts`. I have a variable inside folder-selector.ts called `pathToNode`. How do I access this value from `home.ts`? My home component has an import for FolderSelectorService - I originally thought that maybe I would need to create a service call to reference pathToNode but that doesn't seem right. Basically how do I get component values between components? Am I supposed to have an import statement for the folder-selector component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data to (child) components should be done through `@Input`, read https://toddmotto.com/passing-data-angular-2-components-input and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

It's important to get familiar with data flows in Angular 2 to create apps, data flows down through `@Input`, events flow up through `@Output`

You can only pass data down in your component tree, so this requires for your `home` component to be nested inside `folder-selector`.
(If that is not the case, you'd have to create a parent component which holds the data)

```
<folder-selector>
    <home [pathToNode]="pathToNode"> ...</home>
</folder-selector
```